# SQL - Create "virtual" column based on data from other columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a some issues with a SQL query I'm working on, I'm sorry that I don't have any work-in-progress to show because nothing that I have tried until now have worked out too well, so I am hoping that someone will be able to point me in the right direction.

**Tables:**

Computers:

```
[SN][PN][ComputerName][Model][OS][Architecture][RAM][CPU]
```

Logons:

```
[SN][Username][Timestamp]
```

**Info:**

It works this way, every time a user logs on to a computer the computer info gets updated to the computer table and the username and timestamp gets inserted to the logons table.

**Result**

The result I am trying to acheive is the following:

```
[SN][PN][ComputerName][Model][OS][Architecture][RAM][CPU]**[Primary User]**
```

It should be only one row for each computer

The Primary User field should be based from the 5 latest logons and being the username with the most recurrences in those 5.

So I think that wraps It up, I hope someone here is able to at least point me in the right direction as every result google have to offer now show up as red.

Comment: What `[Primary User]` should be shown  if the last 5 logins are (in order) `bob, alice, charles ,alice, bob`?

Comment: Well, if that ever get to be the case, i guess it can be the latest one or random.

Comment: And by virtual column you mean something that shows up as a column in the table as per @Norla's answer or just a column that is appended to a select query?

Comment: I think the best way would be not to alter the DB, so if it is possible I would like to append it to the result with a query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bit RBAR but something like the following should do it.

```
SELECT [SN],
       [PN],
       [ComputerName],
       [Model],
       [OS],
       [Architecture],
       [RAM],
       [CPU],
       O.[Username] AS [Primary User]
FROM   Computers C
       OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 [Username]
                    FROM   (SELECT TOP (5) *
                            FROM   Logons L
                            WHERE  L.[SN] = C.[SN]
                            ORDER  BY [Timestamp] DESC) Last5Users
                    GROUP  BY [Username]
                    ORDER  BY Count(*) DESC,
                              Max([Timestamp]) DESC) O
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks a lot Martin! It's making me kind of sad that I have tried a whole day to achieve something you cooked together in 5, but mostly happy :) Have a great one!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to define a computed column.  Check out this question: [Creating a computed column in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038221/creating-a-computed-column-in-sql-server-2008)

Comment: Thank you for the response, I was not aware of this functionality! But I'm not sure if this approach suits my needs in this particular case, but I will definitely look more into it. Thanks again!

Comment: I misread "virtual column" as "I want all this jazz in a single column."  Please consider using commas to separate columns.