# how add data to sql server with query sequence?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sequence

Im using sql server 2008.

how i insert data to sql server 2008 with combine text and number with together ?
for example add record sequency :

```
me1
me2
me3
me4
.
.
.
```

how i write query for this ?

Comment: If possible I recommend to use some programming language to generate a big insert script for you. If not, It's possible with T-SQL

Comment: yes i want t-sql code

Answer (score 1):

Try to create `Computed Column`. Please refer the links for more details

1. [Specify Computed Columns in a Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188300.aspx)
2. [Creating a computed column in SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038221/creating-a-computed-column-in-sql-server-2008)
3. [Computed Column Specification in SQL Server](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19641/Computed-Column-Specification-in-SQL-Server)

Computed columnn specification can have column as parameters. Like
`('me'+CONVERT([nvarchar](20),[ID],(0)))`, where `me` is your text and `ID` is the an identity column.

For existing data, you can use an update statement.

```
WITH X AS 
( 
    SELECT 
        'me'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), row_number() over (order by ExistingColumn)) RNum,
        * 
    FROM YourTable
) 
UPDATE X SET NewColumn=x.RNum
```