# SQL to Sum columns in a row

Tags: sql, asp.net

I have an sql that gives me this data:

```
    Dim MySqlString As String = "SELECT USERID, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when ACTVCODE = 'POC' then 1 else 0 end) POC, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when ACTVCODE = 'PIC' then 1 else 0 end) PIC, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when ACTVCODE = 'EML' then 1 else 0 end) EML, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when ACTVCODE = 'AD' then 1 else 0 end) AD, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when RESULTCODE = 'LOG' then 1 else 0 end) LOG, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when RESULTCODE = 'SR' then 1 else 0 end) SR, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when RESULTCODE = 'DM' then 1 else 0 end) DM, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when RESULTCODE = 'GK' then 1 else 0 end) GK, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when RESULTCODE = 'AM' then 1 else 0 end) AM, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when RESULTCODE = 'NA' then 1 else 0 end) NA, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when RESULTCODE = 'RO' then 1 else 0 end) RO, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when RESULTCODE = 'ORE' then 1 else 0 end) ORE, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when RESULTCODE = 'COM' then 1 else 0 end) COM, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when RESULTCODE = 'SMS' then 1 else 0 end) SMS, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when RESULTCODE = 'SV' then 1 else 0 end) SV, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when RESULTCODE = 'QUO' then 1 else 0 end) QUO, "
    MySqlString += "SUM(case when RESULTCODE = 'PQU' then 1 else 0 end) PQU "
```

[image: Data]

I am trying to add a column at the end that will sum up each row. I tried using SUM(POC + PIC + EML + AD + LOG) but that did not work the way I thought it would. Any suggestions?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images.

Comment: Could you add your query too?

Comment: Just use basic Math a+b+c+d+e=Total  or you could use a [computed column](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx) to have the value "stored" so you can retrieve it w/o the overhead when called.  Overhead is on save. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038221/creating-a-computed-column-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Why store numerical data in varchar columns? Use proper integer data type instead.

Comment: They are int's it's actually giving me an error saying these are invalid column names

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to SUM:

`POC + PIC + EML + AD + LOG`

Comment: Just to note, if any of the columns are `NULL` then the sum will be `NULL`.

Comment: `coalesce(poc,0) + coalesce(pic,0)... as RowTotal`

Comment: You can also use `ISNULL(poc,0)`

Comment: It's giving me this error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'POC' to data type int

Comment: Did you use `isnull(POC, 0) + isnull(PIC, 0) + ...` ?  What type is POC?

Comment: @KMurray - that's why you need to ask better questions. Anyway, you first need to cast your varchar to an int (or better - fix your schema).

Comment: @VenkataramanR, `COALESCE()` is ANSI SQL, while `ISNULL` is product specific - and no dbms is specified here.

Comment: It seems table header added as a row

Comment: @jarlh, Got it. You are right. I did not check the RDMBS.